# Clique in a certain $18$-regular graph of order $35$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I am studying a certain graph below.

An $18$-regular graph $G$ on $35$ vertices has a property that:

- Every adjacent vertices have $9$ common neighbors

Can I conclude that there is a clique (complete subgraph) of order 7?

My questions (and guesses):

- $G$ is not necessarily a strongly regular graph, is it? As far as I know, we need one more parameter for $G$ to be strongly regular.
- What is a general/known method to tackle this type of problem? I believe Turan's theorem cannot be used here. Do we need probabilistic techniques?

Thank you very much for the guidance and responses.